# Extract chacters from a cell with dynamic attribtutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I will try my best to make this as simple of an explanation as possible.

Cell A1 contains a series of data looking like:

**X001DDWIQ3(607093),X001E6Y98T(81299),X001E6Y98T(81299),X001DDWIQ3(607093),X001R5N087(605253),X00185UHG9(439599),X00185UHG9(439599),X001RPL9AN(37),X001PBDU9R(101),X0017I5MV7(439599)**

Cell B1 is similar and has corresponding data:
**CAE1,CMH1,DFW7,EWR4,MKC6,MKE1,OAK4,ONT2,SNA6**

Cell C1 contains one value from Cell B1
**EWR4**

Since EWR4 is the 4th item in Cell B1 then it coordinates with X001DDWIQ3(607093), the 4th item in cell A1.

Since all of the items in B1 are 4 characters long separated by a comma and no spaces I can use the formula:

```
LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(C1,B1)-1))/5+1
```

to determine the position in B1 that C1 occupies.

What I am trying to do is extract the corresponding value into Cell D1. The only constant information I can extract from what I have now is that the desired value is located between the 3rd and 4th comma, and the characters outside of the parenthesis always have a count of 10. The number in the parenthesis is dynamic, and that is what is stumping me.

I need to determine how many characters up to the 3rd comma and the 4th comma to utilize as my start and stop points for an **=MID**.

Comment: Do you mean `LEN(LEFT(B1,FIND(C1,B1)-1))/5+1`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing out the type-o. I have made the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(C1,B1)-1))/5+1` can be simplfied to:

```
(FIND(C1,B1)-1)/5+1
```

Then we can use that in a mid that adds 99 spaces for every `,` which gives us a large target to find.  Then we trim the return.

Use:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),((FIND(C1,B1)-1)/5)*99+1,99))
```

[image]